# A bug in a string comparison algorithm

Tags: javascript, math

### Description

I'm trying to implement a JS version of Levenshtein distance function, using the matrix method described on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) in Wikipedia.

### Problem

The algorithm works as expected, it returns the difference between the strings (the amount of edits you need to do for strings to be equal), except it ignores index 0, no matter what character is at index 0, it always considers it to be "correct":

```js
levenshteinDistance('cat', 'cave') // 2 (correct)
levenshteinDistance('cat', 'cap')  // 1 (correct)
levenshteinDistance('cat', 'hat')  // 0 (should be 1)
levenshteinDistance('cat', 'rat')  // 0 (should be 1)
levenshteinDistance('cat', 'bat')  // 0 (should be 1)
```

### Code

https://codepen.io/aQW5z9fe/pen/mdPvJqV?editors=0011

```js
function levenshteinDistance (string1, string2, options) {
  if (string1 === string2) { return 0 }
  let matrix = []
  let cost
  let i
  let j

  // Init first column of each row
  for (i = 0; i <= string1.length; i++) {
    matrix[i] = [i]
  }
  // Init each column in the first row
  for (j = 0; j <= string2.length; j++) {
    matrix[0][j] = j
  }

  // Fill in the rest of the matrix
  for (i = 1; i <= string1.length; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= string2.length; j++) {
      // Set cost
      cost = string1[i] === string2[j]
        ? 0 
        : 1
      // Set the distances
      matrix[i][j] = Math.min(
        matrix[i - 1][j] + 1, // deletion
        matrix[i][j - 1] + 1, // insertion
        matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + cost // substitution
      )
      if (
        options.allowTypos &&
        i > 1 &&
        j > 1 &&
        string1[i] === string2[j - 1] &&
        string1[i - 1] === string2[j]
      ) {
        matrix[i][j] = Math.min(
          matrix[i][j], 
          matrix[i - 2][j - 2] + 1
        ) // transposition
      }
    }
  }
  return matrix[string1.length][string2.length]
}

console.log(
  levenshteinDistance('cat', 'hat', { allowTypos: true })
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just made a small mistake I think this:

```
cost = string1[i] === string2[j]
```

Should be :

```
cost = string1[i-1] === string2[j-1]
```

Since otherwise you never check for the cost of the first letter in the strings and the cost for the letters after that in case of the substitution is always derived from that.

***EDIT***:
The part inside the transpose section/ allow typo section should also be changed from:

```
string1[i] === string2[j - 1] && 
string1[i - 1] === string2[j]
```

to

```
string1[i-1] === string2[j - 2] &&
string1[i - 2] === string2[j-1]
```

After looking at the Wikipedia article they for some reason use 1 indexed arrays for the strings and 0 indexed arrays for the matrix, so I guess that was the root of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The algorithm on the wiki page also compares `string1[i] === string2[j]` however your solution fixed the problem with the `index 0`, except now the `transposition` check stopped working (it's supposed to fix 1 character typo string shift), if I compare `hat, hta` it now returns `2` instead of `1`

Comment: @Alex I think you need to adjust the index of the comparison inside the transpose as well.
Since at one point your checking string[3] which returns undefined. I changed it to `string1[i-1] === string2[j - 2] && string1[i - 2] === string2[j-1]` which seems to work if you find another issue let me know. Otherwise I'll edit my answer and add it.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending your time and finding the problem, your solution fixed the issue! Small issues like this add up very quickly when you're building a big app. I'm building a modern, free, and open source file manager app (for Windows, Mac, Linux), One of its features is a very quick, smart file search that allows you to find any file / directory on your computer in a few seconds no matter where it is, even if you misspell all the search words. So after a few days of work, I just finally finished this feature with your help, so thank you!